# What is the word for made up words with no meaning. E.g. Advisia, Tocodi

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for made up words. E.g. Advisia, Tocodi

For example, if I was trying to think of a name for a website, I might just want to use a word tht has no meaning but sounds nice.

I do not mean Neologism which idescribes a relatively recent or isolated term, word, or phrase that may be in the process of entering common use, but that has not yet been fully accepted into mainstream language.

I mean the word for words which will perhaps never have a meaning but sound nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say your website name is a **coined word**.

From [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/coin_2#coin_10):

> **coin** (*verb*) to use a word or phrase that no one has used before

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/coin) says:

> **coin** (*verb*) invent or devise (a new word or phrase)

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coin) defines it like this:

> **coin** (*verb*) to invent a new word or expression, or to use one in a particular way for the first time

*Advisia* and *Tocodi* are coined words.